# Cannot Delete specific record(Document) from mongodb using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

```
router.get('/deleteRecord/delete/:id', function(req, res){
  db.collection('inventories').remove({_id: mongodb.ObjectID( req.params.id)}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log('Welcome to Delete Function');
    res.redirect('deleteRecord');
  });
});
```

handlebars: [Delete](/deleteRecord/delete/%7B%7B_id%7D%7D)

Gettting the ID back but record isn't being deleted

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 db.collection('inventories').find({_id: mongodb.ObjectID( req.params.id)}).remove()
```